# How to extract column labels only from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to extract column labels only which has time format from data frame. My data looks like below

[image: My data looks like this]

and I want to get only data like `06-Dec-2020,07-Dec-2020,08-Dec-2020,09-Dec-2020,10-Dec-2020,11-Dec-2020,12-Dec-2020`

Looking for great support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the dates might be across multiple months, years,

```
cols = ['blah', '06-Dec-2020', '20-Dec-2020','01-Jan-2021']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = cols)
```

You can convert the dates to datetime with errors set to `coerce` which will convert non-dates to NaT. Then filter the columns using boolean indexing,

```
pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format = '%d-%b-%Y', errors='coerce').notna()

array([False,  True,  True,  True])

df.columns[pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format = '%d-%b-%Y', errors='coerce').notna()].tolist()
```

Output:

```
['06-Dec-2020', '20-Dec-2020', '01-Jan-2021']
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `filter` with `regex` pattern:

```
df.filter(regex=r'\d{2}-\w{3,}-\d{4}').columns
```

Result:

```
Index(['06-Dec-2020', '07-Dec-2020', '08-Dec-2020', '09-Dec-2020',
       '10-Dec-2020', '11-Dec-2020', '12-Dec-2020'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: I'd assume the OP wants december dates only, so maybe ``df.filter(like='Dec').columns`` would save some regex. Again, just an assumption

Comment: @sammywemmy Correct! If OP wants to filter only december dates then surely `df.filter(like='Dec').columns` is a more concise way to go :-)